# UIDatePicker in UIViewController is showing error

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I am trying to link `UIDatePicker` to a text field so that if I select a particular date, it gets in the `textField`. I am getting errors

```swift
import UIKit

 class tiViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
   let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showDatePicker()
}


func showDatePicker(){
    //Formate Date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date /* ERROR 1 
      - Value of type 'UIDatePicker' has no member 'datePickerMode'*/

    //ToolBar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar();
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));

    toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

    txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker
}

@objc func donedatePicker(){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    txtDatePicker.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
 }


@objc func cancelDatePicker(){
    self.view.endEditing(true) /* ERROR 2  - Value of type 'UIDatePicker' has no member 'date'*/
}
```

it shows above ERROR1 AND ERROR2
I have also linked tiviewcontroller to textfield outlet properly -

[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the data cache? Click on 
`Product > Clean build folder` while pressing alt/option. Or delete the derived data folder (from settings>location). Then recompile.

Comment: Sometimes you will see unexpected errors because of other actual errors. To verify that, just comment these lines of code and fix the rest of errors before uncommenting again.

Comment: its Working fine in Swift 5, Xcode 11....., i can send you a demo...

Comment: @kamaran - I commented those lines of code.build succeeds but date does not get displayed in textfield. on uncommenting those lines, it shows error.

Comment: @jalone - tried that.

Comment: @SaifanNadaf - I do not what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I have also edited the code slightly. Few upper lines were missing(sorry for that ). maybe  I am doing something wrong, because I have just linked above "txtDatePicker". I have not linked up func showDatePicker() and   @objc func donedatePicker() to storyboard. Is that creating a problem ? Please help me guys, it really eating up time.

Comment: i have uploaded a demo check it.....https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hQIzQLkakLiPDny0OnvdE9x3mcpVxstk